# IOS UIPopoverBackgroundView, set different content insets

Tags: ios, ipad, popover

Ive implemented a CustomPopOverBackgroundView which is a subclass of UIPopoverBackgroundView.

Ive implemented the class method

```
+(UIEdgeInsets)contentViewInsets{   
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(CONTENT_INSET, CONTENT_INSET, CONTENT_INSET, CONTENT_INSET);
}
```

and at the moment CONTENT_INSET is fixed value:

```
#define CONTENT_INSET 25.0
```

What I would like to do, is to be able to change this value so I can have different popovers  across the app with diferent content insets.

Is it possible having just one popoverbackground class?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a perfect way to do that and I think it's lame that Apple's API doesn't allow us to create the instances of the background class on our own.

However, a kinda tedious workaround is to create a static method like setContentViewInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)insets to change the value of a static variable such like contentViewInsets which then can be returned by the +(UIEdgeInsets)contentViewInsets method.

So then, you have to call "setContentViewInsets" every time you need to change the contentViewInsets. It's kinda annoying, but that's the "best" way I can think of without creating a bunch of background classes.

By the way, changing the contentViewInsets at runtime will have an animation side effect, which, for me, is also annoying.

I really hope Apple can change the API to take instances instead of the background Class itself.